# Is it possible to switch context to WebView when run automation tests with real android device on mac?

Tags: webview, automation, selenium-chromedriver, appium, ui-automation

I've an issue to run on automation tests with real android device for Hybrid application on mac.
I'm using `appium` and get the following error when trying to switch context from `native` to `WebView`:

> Original error: chrome not reachable

Is it possible to switch context to WebView when run automation tests on real android device from mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be due to the default web browser used in the Android phone. In the phones which have a different web browser like Samsung Web Browser in Samsung phones, the default browser won't be set to Chrome. In this case, please set the default browser to Chrome and restart the phone once. Webviews will now start opening using Chrome.

Comment: I tried it but no luck. Still getting the same error. 
Any other idea ?

Comment: Need to debug further. One thing that you can try out `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com`. Please confirm if this opens in chrome itself. Also regarding the error, is it possible to share the complete error logs?

Comment: Solved. Issue was related to chromedriver version and where to locate it. I downloaded chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and locate it both on /usr/local/bin and on /Users/{username}/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac
Also add those paths to PATH in environment variables.
In addition make sure the correct WebView version is installed on the android device. This version should fits to the chromedriver version.
If not fits download the appropriate WebView version from https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to compatibility of `chromedriver`  and `Android webview`  on your real device. Try to upgrade and give it a try. You can upgrade it from below links

•   [phone webview](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview/)

•   [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

Comment: I tried it but no luck. Still getting the same error. 
Any other idea ?